# Comparing multiclass LDA and logistic regression equations

Tags: logistic, discriminant-analysis, multi-class

I was told that LDA and logistic regression is the same, when we consider 2 class situation. That I can also confirm (I think), for LDA

$$\log \frac{Pr(Y=1|X=x)}{Pr(Y=0|X=x)} \\
= \frac{f_1(x)\pi_1}{f_0(x)\pi_0}\\
=\log\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}+\log\frac{\pi_1}{\pi_0}\\
= \log\frac{\pi_1}{\pi_0}-\frac{1}{2}(\mu_1+\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)+x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)\\
= \alpha+w^Tx$$

and for logistic regression

$$\log \frac{Pr(Y=1|X=x)}{Pr(Y=0|X=x)}\\
= \log \frac{Pr(Y=1)p(x|Y=1)}{Pr(Y=0)p(x|Y=0)}\\
= \log \frac{\pi_1\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\Sigma|}}\exp({-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_1)})}{\pi_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\Sigma|}}\exp({-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_0)})}\\
= \log\frac{\pi_1}{\pi_0}-\frac{1}{2}(\mu_1+\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)+x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)\\
= \alpha+w^Tx$$

where $w^T=\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_0-\mu_1)$.

But when I try to do the same for multiclass, I get stuck. I read that these are not the same, but should still be "proportional" to each other.

So I start looking into it and I think I get the LDA one right as

$$\log Pr(Y=k|X=x)\\
= f_k(x)\pi_k \\ 
= C'' + \log\pi_k - \frac{1}{2}\mu_k^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k+x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_k$$

where $C''$ is non-k-dependant constant. But then trying to construct $Pr(Y=k|X=x)$ I only get this far

$$Pr(Y=k|X=x) = \frac{1}{1+\Sigma_{k=1}^{K-1}e^{\beta_kx_i}}$$

and haven't have managed to get this further to the same format as with the LDA equation.

So basically, what I would like to do here is to see how does one construct the comparable equations for the the multi class LDA and logistic regression and how do they differ and what is the proportion in which they differ.